# Convert a .ui file to .py file with PyQt5 and python 3.6

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

Converting a .ui file to a .py file using cmd

`C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/pyuic.cpython-36.pyc -x mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py`

The error shows like

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I checked the path, unfortunately, there is no file named in the PyQt folder

please, someone, check this problem

Comment: Is there no other file that has the name of pyuic?

Comment: search `pyuic5.exe` on `C:/Python36/Scripts` then execute: `C:\Python36\Scripts\pyuic5.exe -x mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py`- source: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5qcrdh/qt_designer_convert_ui_to_py_cant_find_pyuic5bat/

Comment: @ellanesc still the same error occurs :(

Comment: Have you opened the CMD in the directory of the folder where mainwindow.ui is located?

Comment: Yes. I found the answer @ellanesc first we need to copy the ui file to the folder where is pyuic5.exe file ie, in Scripts folder then by a creating a command window and following command will create the py file  `pyuic5.exe mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py -x`

Comment: I do not think it's good that you do that, the correct thing is that you open a terminal that is located in the .ui folder for it in any CMD executes: `cd "/path/of/directory/where/are/.ui"` and then you execute: `/path/of/pyuic5.exe -x your.ui -o your_py.py`

Comment: `C:\Users\Aju\Documents\untitled>C:/Python36/scripts/pyuic5.exe mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py -x` where untiled is the folder containing my ui file but still the error  `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to the above

first, we need to locate the pyuic5.exe file and copy your ui file to the same location.
then, we have to create a command prompt and give the command will give the python file .

`pyuic5.exe mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py -x`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but it might help someone

Tested on windows 10 pro, python 3.9.10, Pyqt 6.2.3

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import traceback


# create folders for storing ui files and for storing py file in your project
#.project
#    ui_pyfiles
#        __init__.py
#        ui_pyfile1.py
#        ui_pyfile2.py
#    ui_xmlfiles
#        ui_xmlfile1.ui
#        ui_xmlfile2.ui
#    convert_uifile.py
#    main.py

# keep path of ui file and path of py file in a dictionary, 
# use name of ui file as key (or any other name, your choice)
file_paths = {
  'main_window': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\main_window.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_main_window.py')],
  'file_display_list_mode': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\file_display_list_mode.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_file_display_list_mode.py')],
  'playlistview': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\playlistview.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_playlistview.py')],
  'property_item_display': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\property_item_display.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_property_item_display.py')],
  'group_property_display': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\group_property_display.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_group_property_display.py')],
  'properties_display': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\properties_display.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_properties_display.py')],
  # 'window_v2': [os.path.abspath('.\\ui_xmlfiles\\window_v2.ui'), os.path.abspath('.\\ui_pyfiles\\ui_window_v2.py')],
}

# provide full path of folder containing pyuic6.exe
# on windows run 'where pyuic6' on cmd to locate pyuic6.exe then grab the dir
pyuic6_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Hp\\pyvenv\\pyqt6_python3_9_10.venv\\Scripts'
current_working_dir = os.getcwd()

def do_convert(key_: str):
  """@param key_: str -> name of ui file (a key in the file_paths dictionary)"""

  if key_.lower() in ('*', 'all'):
    for key_ in file_paths: do_convert(key_)
  
  uifile_path = file_paths[key_][0]
  pyfile_path = file_paths[key_][1]

  # create the py files folder if it does not exist
  # here, i'm considering the folder as package, create __init__.py file
  dir_ = os.path.split(pyfile_path)[0]
  if not os.path.exists(dir_):
    os.makedirs(dir_); open(f'{dir_}\\__init__.py', 'w').close()

  if os.path.getsize(uifile_path) == 0: return

  os.chdir(pyuic6_dir)

  cmd = f'pyuic6 -x {uifile_path} -o {pyfile_path}'

  try:
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
  except Exception as err:
    print(f'an error occured: {str(err)}')
    # traceback.print_exc()
  finally:
    os.chdir(current_working_dir)


def update_imports():
  items = os.listdir('./ui_pyfiles')
  t = ", ".join([item[:-3] for item in items if item.endswith(".py") and not item in ("__init__.py",)])
  t = f'from ui_pyfiles import {t}\n' if t else ""
  with open('./ui_pyfiles/__init__.py', 'w') as file:
    file.seek(0); file.truncate()
    file.write(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    do_convert(sys.argv[1])
    print('success')
  except IndexError:
    print('error: must supply name of ui file to convert to pyfile')
  except KeyError:
    print(f'error: the ui file \'{sys.argv[1]}\' not found. available ui files: ({", ".join(file_paths.keys())})')
  finally:
    update_imports()
```

Save as convert_uifile.py

Usage on cmd: convert_uifile.py main_window

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do this using a batch script.This was an easy solution I found.
Create this Batch script in the directory where you made your project and let it do all the work. If there are one or more files with ui extension, find automatically converts them to py file. If there is no file with ui extension, it will not perform the operation.

```
@echo OFF

set "mypath=%~dp0"
set "file_=List.tmp"
set "LINES=0"
rem Enter the directory where uic.exe is located in the variable here.
set "uic_=C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner"

dir *.ui  > nul 2>&1 &&(
goto exe_
) || (
goto ex_
)

:exe_

dir *.ui /s /b > %file_%
for /f "delims==" %%I in (%file_%) do (
set /a LINES=LINES+1
)

for /f "tokens=1-%LINES% delims=" %%a in (%file_%) do (
set hh=%%~na
)

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A IN (%file_%) DO (
rem Files are processed and converted from ui to py format.
%uic_%\uic "%mypath%%%~nxA" -o "%mypath%%%~nA.py" -g python
)

goto succ_

:ex_
echo Files does not exist!
pause
goto eex_

:succ_
cd %mypath%
del /Q %file_%
echo Operating Success. Creating python GUI File(s).
pause

:eex_
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).